# Jquery ajax response extract part of html - in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax functions which returns html markup. I need to extract a certain div form the entire string and replace that same div in my current html.
this is part of the code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postUrl,
        dataType: "HTML",
        data: "ddd"
        success: function(htmlResponse) {
                //replace the html code
                $('#somediv').html($('#somediv' htmlResponse).html());
            }
        },
```

Works fine in Chrome and FF, not in IE 8. IE doesn'f find the div in the htmlResponse. i tried alerting:

```
alert($(htmlResponse).find('#somediv').html());
```

and got a blank message.
Is this a bug in IE, is anything wrong in my code?
Thanks 8

Comment: Could you please add the content of `htmlResponse` to your question.

Comment: it's the whole html document can't really post it. can the content of htmlReponse affect the behavior of IE only?

Comment: IE is an unwieldy beast which plays by it's own rules ;) Have you checked the console for errors in IE?

Comment: maybe test by replacing the htmlResponse with something other than html document (eg: `htmlRepsonse = "test";`) and see what it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `alert`, I can't think of why IE would break on `alert($(htmlResponse).find('#somediv').html());` unless the html() that was grabbed was just oversized / too much whitespace / empty in the first place.

However, on this line:

```
$('#somediv').html($('somediv' htmlResponse).html());
```

did you mean:

```
$('#somediv').html($('#somediv', htmlResponse).html());
```

?

Edit:

It might be a good idea to analyze the HTML in `htmlResponse`, and make sure it is well formed.  Maybe a `<div>` doesn't close, or other invalid syntax that IE8 is having trouble with.

Comment: thanks, i will have a look at it again, even though it should be well structured. if the html response has both xml and html in it, what should the dataType be?

Comment: If it's a properly formed XML document, it would be `dataType: 'xml'` If a `somediv` node that contains properly formatted HTML is inside of your XML, you would then use `$('#somediv').html($('somediv', htmlResponse).html());`

Answer (score 1):

in your postUrl, add " #divID", this will return only the div you are looking for.
e.g.

```
var postUrl = "/something/target.htm #theDiv";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postUrl,
    dataType: "HTML",
    data: "ddd"
    success: function(htmlResponse) {
            //replace the html code
            $('#somediv').html($('somediv' htmlResponse).html());
        }
    },
```

I can't recall off the top of my head whether this works for $.ajax or $.get, but I know for a fact that it works for $('#somediv').load(), which could be an alternative, shorter, approach:

```
$('#somediv').load("/something/target.htm #theDiv");
```

You can obviously insert a querystring into the URL, as long as the #divID is at the end.

Comment: this is a small snippet of a very big picture so the postul must stay as it is :(

Comment: You can also pass postUrl +" #theDiv" to your call, so postUrl can stay the same.